# How do you make a Ninject Provider when the constructor of type is not known?

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, ioc-container, ninject, fubumvc

I decided to try to conjure up a container assembly to interact with
FubuMVC. Well the cool part is that it pass all the test that the
FubuMVC.Container.StructureMap assembly does. However, when I dropped
it into the FubuSample. I received an activation error.

The error is because in the provider for the behaviors I'm only
calling a parameterless constructor to build behavior instances. That
is unacceptable in real life it would seem.

Here is how it is set up:

```
public class TestBehavior2 : IControllerActionBehavior
{
    public IControllerActionBehavior InsideBehavior { get; set; }
    public IInvocationResult Result { get; set; }
    protected FubuConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }
    protected FubuConventions Conventions { get; set; }

    public TestBehavior2(FubuConventions conventions, FubuConfiguration config)
    {
        Conventions = conventions;
        Configuration = config;
    }

    public OUTPUT Invoke<INPUT, OUTPUT>(INPUT input, Func<INPUT, OUTPUT> func)
        where INPUT : class
        where OUTPUT : class
    {
        // Invocation stuff
    }
}

public class TestBehavior : IControllerActionBehavior
{
    public IControllerActionBehavior InsideBehavior { get; set; }
    public IInvocationResult Result { get; set; }
    public OUTPUT Invoke<INPUT, OUTPUT>(INPUT input, Func<INPUT, OUTPUT> func)
        where INPUT : class
        where OUTPUT : class
    {
        // Invocation stuff
    }
}
```

My Load method has these binding in it:

```
foreach (var actionConfig in _configuration.GetControllerActionConfigs())
{
    Bind(actionConfig.ControllerType).ToSelf();

    Bind<IControllerActionBehavior>()
        .ToProvider(new BehaviorInstanceProvider(actionConfig))
        .WhenParentNamed(actionConfig.UniqueID);

    Bind<IControllerActionInvoker>().To(actionConfig.InvokerType)
        .Named(actionConfig.UniqueID);
}
```

In my provider's Create method is:

```
public object Create(IContext context)
{
    var behavior = ConfigureInstance(context);
    foreach (var type in _config.GetBehaviors().Reverse())
    {
        IControllerActionBehavior previousBehavior = behavior;
        behavior = (IControllerActionBehavior)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        t.GetProperty(INSIDE_PROP_NAME).SetValue(behavior, temp, null);
    }
    return behavior;
}
```

So my question is how should I set up to provider to create an
instance of a service when all I don't know what the constructor will
look like? Or rather if I use the ConstructorInfo to ascertain the
constructor will Ninject inject the appropriate dependencies?

This is using Ninject 2b, since FubuMvc requires CommonServiceLocator
support.

Comment: Could you provide some example code?  I'm not sure how exactly you are using the provider?

Comment: Note that Ninject will resolve any arguments in your Provider's constructor, if it can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I found that I was making thing more complicated than it had to be. Here is my new Create method:

```
public object Create(IContext context)
{
    IControllerActionBehavior behavior = context.Kernel.Get<DefaultBehavior>();
    _config.GetBehaviors().Reverse().Each(t =>
                                          {
                                              var temp = behavior;
                                              behavior = (IControllerActionBehavior) context.Kernel.Get(t);
                                              t.GetProperty(INSIDE_PROP_NAME).SetValue(behavior, temp, null);
                                          });
    _type = behavior.GetType();
    return behavior;
}
```

All I had to do was just get the concrete behavior types and everybody was happy.